# why does border css shrink width in firefox

Tags: html, css, textbox, width, border

i have this css to highlight input when they are in focus:

```
input:focus, textarea:focus{  
  background-color: #FFFF99;  
  border-width: 1px;  
  border-style:solid;  
  border-color:Black;  
}
```

i just noticed that when i click on a textbox it shrinks by a very small but noticable amount.  Is there any reason why the css above would change the width & height of a textbox when i have it in focus?

i am using firefox 3.16

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it shrinks because the default borders of a `textarea` `input` are 2-3px and you're only overriding them to 1px in the focus state

it won't shrink if you override the default borders to be the same width e.g.:

```
input, textarea {
  border: 1px solid #444;
}

input:focus, textarea:focus{  
 background-color: #FFFF99;  
 border-width: 1px;  
 border-style:solid;  
 border-color:Black;  
 }
```

### Update

to retain original dimensions without recalculating for borders this appears to work:

```
input, textarea {
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -ms-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  width: 300px;
  height: 50px;

}

input:focus, textarea:focus{  
 background-color: #FFFF99;  
 border-width: 1px;  
 border-style:solid;  
 border-color:#000;  
 }
```

Comment: does your textarea/input have widths on them?.. if so adjust the width and height accordingly to 1 or 2px more when they're focused.. I think also this may be difficult crossbrowser as the different browsers handle UI elements different and their defaults may not be consistent across browser .. maybe box-sizing.. will take a look

Comment: yes, box-sizing will do it as long as the elements have a height and width too.. see updated answer

Answer (score 0):

It's due to the [Box Model](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/box.html).

When you apply 1px border width, it has to "eat" 2px (1 for each side) horizontally and vertically from your element.

Comment: thanks, do you have any suggestions to work around this.  do i need to add javascript to increase the width and height by 2 px ??

Comment: You could use js, but it still depends on the implementation of the css for inputs, if you can [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) the css and some html for the inputs, I'll take a look at possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

This may work:

```
input, textarea {
  border: 1px solid #444;
  paddding:1px
}

input:focus, textarea:focus{  
 background-color: #FFFF99;  
 border-width: 1px;  
 border-style:solid;  
 border-color:Black; 
padding:0 
 }
```